# Adding string interpolation within backticked strings

Tags: go, string-interpolation

I am trying to figure out how to interpolate within backticked string literals.

i.e.

```
myVar := "this is my var"
var jsonStr = []byte(`{
  "attachments": [
        {   
            "text": "Hello World! {{myVar}}"

        }
    ]
}`)
```

`{{myVar}}` this is just pseudo code to get my intent across, but how would I do this in golang?

Comment: Do not do this! Use packge encoding/json to generate JSON and nothing else.

Comment: There is no string interpolation in Go. You'd have to use a package (possibly the stdlib template package). But that's a silly approach in your specific example. Just use the proper json marshaler instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a template:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "text/template"
)


func main() {
  myVar := "this is my var"
  var jsonStr = `{
  "attachments": [
        {   
            "text": "Hello World! {{.myVar}}"

        }
    ]
}`
 t,_:=template.New("text").Parse(jsonStr)
 out:=bytes.Buffer{}
 t.Execute(&out,map[string]interface{}{"myVar":myVar})
}
```

Comment: so what do I grab to pass in as payload? `req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))` <--- this doesn't work

Comment: The buffer has your string: `http.NewRequest("POST",url,&out)`

Comment: doesn't work :( `cannot use '&out' (type *Buffer) as type []byte`

Comment: `http.NewRequest` takes an `io.Reader`, are you sure you're getting the error at that line? In any case, &out is an `io.Reader`, and if you need ` []byte` from it, call `out.Bytes()`.